# Disposing of Vuex State When Changing Views in Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I am building a web-app in Vue3 similar to [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/), where I have a single page devoted to the creation of games. On this page, I need to track some data about the game in a store, so all components can access it. For example, I need to track the list of Sprites in the game and the currently selected Sprite in the game. These objects are referenced throughout the view in multiple components. Currently, I am storing it all into Vuex.

However, should the user return to the home page (or forum page, etc..), the data stored in Vuex has no meaning anymore! There is no need to keep track of the 'list of Sprites' when there is no game being created!

I'll use the design of Scratch as an example:
[image]

1. The **Editor** component must show the code for the Selected Sprite.
2. The **Stage** must render the reactive list of all Sprites.
3. The **Sprite Selector** must render (and modify) the list of all Sprites.

So these Sprite objects must be stored in **some kind of state**.

My question is this: What Vue3 way to dispose of this state when the user switches pages and is no longer creating a game? Should I implement a simple store for this view as described [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/state-management.html#simple-state-management-from-scratch)? Is Vuex only proper for single-page applications or can it be used in this context?

I also have the idea of using a separate Vue App to hold the Create page. For example:

```js
const createGameApp = createApp({
   // this is used only for the Create page. It could have its own Vuex!

}).mount('#app-a')

const restOfTheWebsite = createApp({
    // this will be used for everything else

}).mount('#app-b')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vuex, the simplest thing (IMHO) is to just use [replaceState](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/api/#replacestate)

the idea is that you create an object has the store in the default state.

Then when you need to clear the state you can either replace the entire state, or use destructuring to pick which parts stay and which don't.

```js
const defaultState = {
  user: {lastlogin:null, username:null},
  editorStuff: {currentScene:null}
}

const store = createStore({
  state () {
    return JSON.stringify(defaultState) // or create a deep copy some other way
  },
  mutations: {
    clearEditor(state) {
      const newState = {...state, editorStuff:defaulfState.editorStuff}
      Object.assign(state, newState) 
      // or...
      store.replaceState(JSON.stringify(defaultState))
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: Interesting idea! I think this is pretty much a homebrew style [Vuex Module](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html). I think I will try the modules route.

Comment: if you're using modules, you can implement similar thing at module level. But if you're using  `replaceState` (instead of re-assigning at module level), that AFAIK, _"Replace[s] the store's root state"_